# How to convert anything to a String safely in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, security, firefox-addon, gecko

If I have:

```
var test = {toString: function(){alert("evil code"); return "test";}};
```

how can I convert `test` to a string? without calling `test.toString()` and without using a `typeof x == "string"` check since I want to allow non strings.

Note: this is for a FF extension dealing with objects from a content page's js scope.

Comment: What do you expect to return without calling `toString()`?

Comment: Well, there's always JSON serializers...

Comment: I've fixed the example syntax.

Comment: Can anything be converted to a string? how would you expect JSON class be represented as a 'safe string'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JavaScript allows you to modify the properties of pretty much any object that is accessible to your script, including `Object.prototype` itself, meaning *any* object is vulnerable to "evil code" in the manner that you explained.

Only primitives are guaranteed to be safe, so the only way to ensure that "evil code" is never executed is to do something like this:

```
function safeToString(x) {
  switch (typeof x) {
    case 'object':
      return 'object';
    case 'function':
      return 'function';
    default:
      return x + '';
  }
}
```

Comment: For folks that need more granularity (e.g still wish to translate `[1,2,3]` to `'1,2,3'` CSV) using something like [Lodash array](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#isArray)/[object detection](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#isObject) could be placed in the object case: `return _.isArray(x) && !_.some(x, _.isObject) ? _.toString(x) : 'object';`

Answer (score 9):

Sadly, @Matthew Flaschen's (currently accepted) answer does not work with the `Symbol` class from ES6 / ES2015:

```
console.log("" + Symbol("foo"));
// results in an exception: 
//   `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string` 
// (at least in Chrome as of this writing).
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L8adq9y4/

(I have no idea why, as `Symbol` has a perfectly good `toString()` method:)

```
console.log(Symbol("foo").toString());
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v1rqfhru/

There's a solution though: the `String()` function seems to be able to convert any value (at least out of the ones I tried) into a `String`. It will even call `toString()` if it exists:

```
console.log(String("A String"));
console.log(String(undefined));
console.log(String(null));
console.log(String({value: "An arbitrary object"}));
console.log(String({toString: function(){return "An object with a toString() method";}}));
console.log(String(function(){return "An arbitrary function"}));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6uc83tsc/

So, pass anything you like into `String()` and you'll get a pretty good result.

Comment: "Pass anything you like into `String()` and you'll get a pretty good result." Not quite. `String([Symbol('AAAA')])` gives "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string".

Answer (score 6):

Your `(toString: function(){alert("evil code"); return "test";})` doesn't even get parsed here, it throws a syntax error. I think you wanted to use `{}` instead of `()`.

Normally you *could* use an empty string and the plus operator to perform a cast:

```
""+test;
""+2; // "2"
""+4.5 // "4.5"
""+[1, 2, 3] // "1,2,3"
""+{} // '[object Object]'
```

But here, there's no real way to convert the object safely.

You can use `delete test.toString` to get rid of the overridden method, after that it will fall back to the normal `toString` method which returns `'[object Object]'`. You can also convert the `toString` method itself into a string via `test.toString.toString()`.

```
"function () { alert("evil code"); return "test"; }"
```

It's up to you what you exactly want to do here.

Comment: This will still implicitly call the "evil" `toString`.

Comment: @Matthew Indeed it's 5:30 am here and his example code is broken too, gonna update it.

Comment: The evil code could be part of a toString attached to the prototype chain, so `delete test.toString()` won't always work.

Answer (score 6):

One option is:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(test)
```

This gives:

```
"[object Object]"
```

in the case of test.  Basically, it just gives type information.  However, I wonder what the exact scenario is here.  How is the evil object getting loaded into the page?  If they can execute arbitrary code on the page, you're basically out of luck.  Among other things, it is then possible to redefine `Object.prototype.toString`.

Comment: Even this isn't foolproof because it's possible to override `Object.prototype.toString`.

Comment: @casa, true.  This really only helps if all they can do is pass a self-contained object into the page.  If they can modify properties of globals, all bets are off.

Comment: here's the catch, the evil code is created in a different scope than my code. It's a FF ext dealing with a content page's scope. So the objects coming from that scope should have a different Object.prototype, so using `Object.prototype.toString` should be safe.

Comment: I think that a combination of this answer and casablanca's switch should do the trick.

Comment: This is the only answer that works for a `const test = Object.create(null)`, which is not wholly uncommon.

Comment: `Object.prototype.toString.call(123)` returns the string `"[object Number]"`. Possibly not what you want to use, as the data (123) is lost...

Answer (score 1):

You can check only `undefined` cases and convert it to using `String` constructor
like this.

`let a = [1,2,3]`

`String(a)`

Exceptional case : `String(undefined) --> "undefined"`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash toString method.

```
_.toString(null);
// => ''

_.toString(-0);
// => '-0'

_.toString([1, 2, 3]);
// => '1,2,3'
```

[Link to documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#toString)

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript the function `String` is Janus-faced.

- If called as a constructor it will create an object.
- If called as a function if will coerces every value into a primitive string.

```js
console.log(typeof new String())
console.log(typeof String())
```

So just use `String(anything)` **without** `new`.